# Javascript: Parsing unicode character string in Chrome and Firefox gives different results

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, firefox, unicode

I created a JSON string of an object in Google Chrome that contained some special characters. 
When I try to parse the resulting string in Javascript using JSON.parse(), Chrome outputs the correct initial object.
However when I try to parse the JSON encoded string in Firefox, the result will contain some encoded unicode characters and differ from the initial object. Does anyone know why that happens and what I can do to avoid it?

```js
//initial json encoded object
let test = "{\"type\":3,\"body\":\"3(¤d\\b101\\u0012!\\u0005\u0090¡\\u0002\u0085W½CNWùaIkwO\u0093£, ß\\u0019¢k\\u0019\\bÇ\u008fwW\u0088J@\\u001a!\\u0005\\u0014+\\\"\u0080:m¸+ò|¼¼B\\u0002\\u0011«êÌ\u00998oO\\u0017\u009b[\u0095ûd[Ð¾&\\\"\u0092\\u00013\\n!\\u00055L\u009cGYÎB¾\u0085Üí\\u000b­êkm?µÏÊ9\u0097ïK\u0080\u0098\\u000f¦\u007f\\u0001Ì1\\u0010\\u0000\\u0018\\u0000\\\"` ¢óÚT$\\u0007:yÈÄ´\\u0013BtüQ\\r\u00850EÌ½È`ñ\u0091\\u0017SFQ{¯\\u0004´å³¥É\u0092\u0090Ra*\u0082J\u007f¸\u009aìQ`)ÀÌ\u0087´<øÜ3­¶+\\u00124Kxlý\u0098\u0098A\\u001f5ÙH\\u0014\u0099à©\\u000eW\\u0010\\u0017rùe9ÖÁ}°ê¿Æ\\u0013åxm\\u000bòf7\",\"registrationId\":\"12149\"}"

//try to parse the object in chrome
let result_chrome = JSON.parse(test);
/*
result_chrome = {type: 3, body: "3(¤d101!¡W½CNWùaIkwO£, ß¢kÇwWJ@!+"…´<øÜ3­¶+4KxlýA5ÙHà©Wrùe9ÖÁ}°ê¿Æåxmòf7", registrationId: "12149"}
*/

//try to parse the object in firefox
let result_firefox = JSON.parse(test);
/*
result_firefox = { type: 3, body: "3(¤d\u0008101\u0012!\u0005\u0090¡\u0002\u0085W½CNWùaIkwO\u0093£, ß\u0019¢k\u0019\u0008Ç\u008fwW\u0088J@\u001a!\u0005\u0014+\"\u0080:m¸+ò|¼¼B\u0002\u0011«êÌ\u00998oO\u0017\u009b[\u0095ûd[Ð¾&\"\u0092\u00013\n!\u00055L\u009cGYÎB¾\u0085Üí\u000b­êkm?µÏÊ9\u0097ïK\u0080\u0098\u000f¦\u007f\u0001Ì1\u0010\u0000\u0018\u0000\"` ¢óÚT$\u0007:yÈÄ´\u0013BtüQ\r\u00850EÌ½È`ñ\u0091\u0017SFQ{¯\u0004´å³¥É\u0092\u0090Ra*\u0082J\u007f¸\u009aìQ`)ÀÌ\u0087´<øÜ3­¶+\u00124Kxlý\u0098\u0098A\u001f5ÙH\u0014\u0099à©\u000eW\u0010\u0017rùe9ÖÁ}°ê¿Æ\u0013åxm\u000bòf7", registrationId: "12149" }
*/
```

Comment: It's just a different way of showing the string content in the console. If you write code to examine the character codes in the resulting strings (via `.charCodeAt()`) they'll be the same.